# Vite+SvelteKit - Environment variables hyper-protection

Tags: environment-variables, vite, sveltekit

I am trying to make a POC and I'm such making a really simple use-case.
In there, I use a `src/lib/db.ts` who, for our interest, contains this code

```js
console.log(import.meta.env.MONGO_URI, import.meta.env.SSR);
```

giving

```js
undefined true
```

Of course, my `.env` file contains a definition for `MONGO_URI`, I tried with `VITE_MONGO_URI` and could see the value.

I know a way to expose it is to use `VITE_MONGO_URI` but my point is exactly *not* to expose it on the client-side.

I checked and the file `db.ts` is not bundled with the client, even the `import.meta.env.SSR` being `true` shows that the bundler knows it's happening on the server.

Question: How to access my private environment variables server-side ?

EDIT: As specified by [Shriji Kondan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3883577/shriji-kondan), the API for this purpose has been created now : [here](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/configuration#env)

Answer (score 2):

It's not very awesome to put secrets on client-side code. It should be either utilities.ts with a performed action `SUPER_SECRET_API_KEY="$ecret@p1Key"` in .env file, then request it via in `src/lib/utilities/utility.js` as explained [here](https://rodneylab.com/getting-started-with-sveltekit/) :

```
import { SUPER_SECRET_API_KEY } from '$env/static/private';
 
export function performApiAction() {
  const apiInstance = initialiseApi({key: SUPER_SECRET_API_KEY});  
}
```

or from page.server.ts via form actions as stated [here](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/form-actions) which is preferable way but it's more complex.

Comment: Indeed, I'm sorry if I didn't bring the answer here, but there was this new development - well described here - that made my question obsolete. Thank you to have specified it out & loud

Comment: Always welcome. Here to help @eddow

Answer (score 1):

You could use `dotenv` on the server side, assuming you are using node-adapter, you can have a file `_constants.ts` in your app

```
import 'dotenv/config';

export const MONGO_URI = process.env.MONGO_URI;
```

and then import this variable into your script.

Comment: This sounds more like a hack than the answer to the question «what is the use of the configuration entries who are not "exposed" and/or how/when to access them»

Comment: If you have declared them in your .env and want to access them on your server, then it is best to use dotenv or you can supply them in your dev, start scripts in your package.json and access them in `process.env.FOO` if you have the `"dev": "FOO=BAR vite dev"`

Comment: Indeed, I understood finally secrret values cannot be accessed with Vite ... https://scottspence.com/posts/sveltekit-env-secrets

Comment: This has changed even further with new sveltekit dynamic/static env
https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/configuration#env
Passing variables on the node commands still work.

Comment: Just a suggestion because you used word "hyper-protection". You could add another layer of protection by using `secure-env` along sveltekit default behavior.